# Azure Speech to Text mic does not stop for continuous recording

Tags: python-3.x, azure, azure-cognitive-services

I am using Azure Speech to text for transcribing audio thru mic/audio files.

```
def speech_continuous_recognize_from_mic():
"""performs one-shot speech recognition from the default microphone"""
# <SpeechRecognitionWithMicrophone>
speech_config = speechsdk.SpeechConfig(subscription=configuration["speech_api"]["speech_key"], region=configuration["speech_api"]["service_region"])
# Creates a speech recognizer using microphone as audio input.
# The default language is "en-us".
speech_recognizer = speechsdk.SpeechRecognizer(speech_config=speech_config)

done = False

def stop_cb(evt):
    """callback that signals to stop continuous recognition upon receiving an event `evt`"""
    print('CLOSING on {}'.format(evt))
    nonlocal done
    done = True

all_results = []
def handle_final_result(evt):
    all_results.append(evt.result.text)

speech_recognizer.recognized.connect(handle_final_result)        

speech_recognizer.session_started.connect(lambda evt: print('\nSESSION STARTED: {}'.format(evt)))
speech_recognizer.session_stopped.connect(lambda evt: print('\nSESSION STOPPED {}'.format(evt)))

speech_recognizer.session_stopped.connect(stop_cb)
speech_recognizer.canceled.connect(stop_cb)

# Start continuous speech recognition
**speech_recognizer.start_continuous_recognition()
while not done:
    time.sleep(1)
print ("####################################################################################")
speech_recognizer.stop_continuous_recognition()
speech_recognizer.session_started.disconnect_all()
speech_recognizer.recognized.disconnect_all()
speech_recognizer.session_stopped.disconnect_all()**
```

stop_continuous_session is not working. Mic is continuously running in the back-end even after force stopping the script

Comment: @V Shriram You might want to take a look at the order of your calls to stop_continuous_recognition() as mentioned in the official sample [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk/blob/master/samples/python/console/speech_sample.py). One user posted a similar [issue](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk/issues/331) on github which got resolved after correcting the call order.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused by infinite loop of the `while not done` code. The code `while not done` is always true, so it's going to go on forever. The stop code will never be executed.